# Get crashed every time while sending values from a fragment in an activity using SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I'm new to android and nothing so much knowledge about getting data from a fragment to an Activity. I have one activity and three fragments named loginFragment, signUpFragment and homeFragment.
I want to do something like when i signup (in signUpFragment)in this app then login using signUp details and go further to homeFrament and HomeFragment has a Logout button that clear the shared preference data and send back to the login screen again.
When the app opens start with loginFragment, if I don't log out then app opens with HomeFragment.

I always get an error while getting data from a fragment in an activity using Sharedpreference.

My codes for getting sharedprefrence value in activity:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
final String email = preferences.getString("email", "Empty");
final String password = preferences.getString("password", "Empty");

final LoginFragment login = new LoginFragment();
final HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();

if (email == "Empty" && password == "Empty" ) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, login).commit();


            }else {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, home).commit();


            }

            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
```

My code for putting data using sharedprefrence in an fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false);

    final EditText et_username = view.findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    final EditText et_remail = view.findViewById(R.id.et_remail);
    final EditText et_rpass = view.findViewById(R.id.et_rpass);
    final EditText et_rcpass = view.findViewById(R.id.et_rcpass);
    final EditText et_phone = view.findViewById(R.id.et_phone);

    preference = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preference.edit();

    view.findViewById(R.id.bt_rsignup).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (LoginFragment.isEmpty(et_username)){
                et_username.setError("Enter user name");
                et_username.requestFocus();
            } else if (LoginFragment.isEmpty(et_remail)) {
                et_remail.setError("Enter email address");
                et_remail.requestFocus();
            } else if (!isEmailValid(et_remail.getText().toString().trim())) {
                et_remail.setError("Enter valid email address");
                et_remail.requestFocus();
            } else if (LoginFragment.isEmpty(et_rpass)){
                et_rpass.setError("Enter password");
                et_rpass.requestFocus();
            } else if (LoginFragment.isEmpty(et_rcpass)) {
                et_rcpass.setError("Repeat password be confirmed");
                et_rcpass.requestFocus();
            } else if (!et_rpass.getText().toString().trim().equals(et_rcpass.getText().toString().trim())) {
                et_rcpass.setError("Password mismatch");
                et_rcpass.requestFocus();
            } else if (LoginFragment.isEmpty(et_phone)){
                et_phone.setError("Enter phone number");
                et_phone.requestFocus();
            } else {
                editor.putString("user_name",et_username.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("email",et_remail.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.putString("password",et_rpass.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.putString("cpassword",et_rcpass.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.putString("phone",et_phone.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.commit();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, loginFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
```

I get this error in logcat :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b005e (com.danish.test3:id/fragment_container) for fragment LoginFragment{52802074 #0 id=0x7f0b005e}
                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it will give error for view not found. menace you have reference view id  that not in your layout check your layout. if you add layout then better to understand.

Comment: check you activity layout R.id.fragment_container exists or not

Comment: I have checked my layout hasn't got any problem, in activity main layout i created a framelayout and named with fragment _container. It works for other fragments and its layout but not working with activity.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use shared preferences to pass data between a fragment and its Activity. Define an interface inside the fragment and let the Activity implement the interface

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, you have provided, the error is that you are trying to access some view which is not present in the current activity or fragment layout.

Either the view is not there or you are passing a wrong view id to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I Think it might work for the three possibilities.Try the three of them independently

> 1.For  all the Fragments change 
>   getFragmentManager()  to    getChildFragmentManager()
>
> 2. Remove **setContentView** for your activity since you are using **.replace**
> 3. Use **FrameLayout** for your replaced fragment activity.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy you are initializing button and calling its setOnclicklistner method as I get from your code and there you were wrong.Before this:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.bt_rsignup).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Add this line:

```
Button btnSignUp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_rsignup);
```

After that instead of this:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.bt_rsignup).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Write this:

```
btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```